# admob xlmns settings for the ad error "required xml attribute adsize was missing"

Tags: android, admob

In the admob testad, in the xmlns:ads settings, which do we use?

1) http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.android.google.gms.ads

2) http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads

3) http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto

In the google developer site, no 3) is used, but when I use it, no ads appear at all. But when I choose 1) or 2), I get an error in place of the ad. A black background with red text saying "required xml attribute adsize was missing" ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this thing in your xml file.

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adUnitId="YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID"
ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

or follow [this](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/banner) and [this](http://androidforbegineers.blogspot.in/2013/08/android-admob-sample-code.html) tutorial for `admob` in your code.